# Angular Can't resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, angular-services

Hi i have this error from angular `Can't resolve all parameters for RoomService: (?).` i have this two files, on is the service.

**room.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ResourceService } from './resource.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { CONFIG as APP_CONSTANTS } from '../config/config';

@Injectable()
export class RoomService extends ResourceService {

  constructor(http) {
    super(http);
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Angular Material
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialComponents } from '../ngcomponents/material.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RoomlistComponent } from './components/roomlist/roomlist.component';

// services
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RoomService } from './services/room.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RoomlistComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialComponents
  ],
  providers: [RoomService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and i don´t have any idea what can the problem, any idea, just in case as you can see the RoomService is extending from another file resourceService i don´t know if that is the problem but i don´t think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

constructor should have `http` parameter as of `Http` type. By which Dependency Resolver will get to know, he should create a token of `Http` injector.

```
constructor(http: Http) {
   super(http);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular can't figure out what to pass because `http` doesn't have a type annotation

```
constructor(http) {
```

If you change it to

```
constructor(http:Http) {
```

and add `HttpModule` to `imports: [...]` of the `AppModule`, it should work.
You also need to add a TypeScript import for `Http`.

See also

- https://angular.io/api/http/HttpModule
- https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Answer (score 0):

in your roomService, you DI should be

```
 constructor(http: Http) {
    super(http);
  }
```